# Phonegap SQLite Plugin Pre-populated Database iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, cordova

I want to distribute a populated database with my app. I am trying to implement the [SQLitePlugin](https://github.com/chbrody/Cordova-SQLitePlugin), but as the page says there is not any documentation for how to do it on iOS. I tried to implement this [outdated](http://gauravstomar.blogspot.ca/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html) steps but without any luck. Is there anyone who did this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the database in the Resources folder and placed this code in `MainViewController.m`.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"this.db"];

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath] == NO) {
    NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"this" ofType:@"db"];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:resourcePath toPath:databasePath error:&error];
}
```

Comment: This worked for me as well. Although PhoneGap had the event webViewDidStartLoad commented by default.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution at least it works for me so here is :

I used and followed the tutorial in the link you mentioned : http://gauravstomar.blogspot.fr/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html

Be sure to copy and past the good database.db and 000...001.db (the good one are either in /Caches and /Caches/file_0 folders or in /WebKit and /WebKit/file__0, i don't remember so try one then the other if it doesn't work). then i pasted them in my resources' project directory.

I modify the two lines :

```
NSString *masterPath = [libraryDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"WebKit/Databases/"];
NSString *databasePath = [libraryDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"WebKit/Databases/file__0/"];
```

by the following lines :

```
NSString *masterPath = [libraryDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Caches/"];
NSString *databasePath = [libraryDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Caches/file__0/"];
```

Remove your application from your simulator/device. And then run.. it works, my database is pre-populated.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try. Where do you put all these code, by the way? Because there is not a `PhoneGapDelegate.m` anymore. And there are more than one `webViewDidStartLoad` event.

Comment: I put these code in my MainViewController.m in the event - (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView.

Comment: Thanks, I vote up your answer. However, I think you are not using that plugin but you are using the built in Webkit database. Anyway, I found out the answer and posted.

Answer (score 0):

The following comes from a blog post - but as I've been slightly spanked for posting links before I'm going to quote from it. I'll post the URL at the end though and I recommend you go there for a full explanation and some follow up comments. This help comes credit Scott Buckel.

1) Use this plugin: https://github.com/chbrody/Cordova-SQLitePlugin/

2) Copy your sqlite db file to /assets folder of PhoneGap.

3) Then, follow instructions here: http://gauravstomar.blogspot.com/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html to copy the file to native storage. Change this.copy("Databases.db","/data/data/"+pName+"/app_database/");

3a) Instead of Databases.db, use your database filename.
3b) Instead of app_database, use "databases"
3c) You'll probably want to delete the file from /assets, since it is duplicated and no longer needed. My app was double the size it needed to be.

4) (Not sure if this step is necessary, I'm getting out of the office for the day). Edit SQLitePlugin.java

4a) Lines 176, I edited 1==1 so that if statement is always executed. Line 179 I changed this.setStorage(appPackage, false); to this.setStorage(appPackage, true);

5) You can then use the following command to open the DB and use it as any other PhoneGap database

5a) var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("[full_database_name_including_extension]", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);

Full blog post: http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/7/27/Guest-Blog-Post-Shipping-a-populated-SQLite-DB-with-PhoneGap

Comment: Thanks, I have seen this, but this is unfortunately for Android, I am looking sth for iOS.